# Detect Android React Native app running under Detox context in MainActivity.java

Tags: java, android, react-native, gradle, detox

I wish to take screenshots of my React Native app from a Detox e2e run when a test fails. This works fine on iOS, but on Android due to the use of `FLAG_SECURE` in my `MainActivity.java`, the screenshots are generated but with zero bytes. On other occasions I get `Command failed` from `ScreencapPlugin` and no files are generated. Essentially, I need a way to detect that the app is being executed from the context of a Detox test run and if so, do not set `FLAG_SECURE`.

My base Detox configuration is:

```
"android.emu.debug": {
    "binaryPath": "android/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk",
    "build": "cd android && ./gradlew app:assembleDebug app:assembleAndroidTest -DtestBuildType=debug && cd ..",
    "type": "android.emulator",
    "device": {
        "avdName": "Pixel_3a_API_27"
    }
}
```

and this is executed using:

```
detox build --configuration android.emu.debug && detox test --configuration android.emu.debug --take-screenshots failing
```

The affected section of `MainActivity.java` looks like:

```
public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {
    // ...

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        getWindow().setFlags(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);

        // ...
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

So far I have tried, to no avail:

- Supplying an additional `P` or `D` argument to the `build` configuration and consuming using `System.getProperty()` in `MainActivity.java` .
- Passing an environment variable in the `build` configuration and consuming using `System.getenv()` in `MainActivity.java`.
- Generating a new `DetoxActivity.java` without the `FLAG_SECURE` being set and wiring up `DetoxTest.java` accordingly.
- Reading `System.getProperty()` in `app.gradle` and assigning to a variable in `defaultConfig`.

Can anybody suggest the best way to get this working? I think I am struggling here as I'm not yet completely to grips with the combination of Detox/Gradle/Java!

Answer (score 2):

In your MainActivity.java

Add:

```java
    protected void onPause() {
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);
        super.onPause();
    }

    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);
    }
```

This will enable FLAG_SECURE only when the application is in the background, but will allow you to be disabled when in the foreground, therefore allowing you to take screenshots.

Comment: This change did allow screenshots to be taken from Detox but also from the actual app running on a real Android device. Is there any other configuration I may have missed?

Comment: You need to check which flavour of app you are using (development vs product) and enable those methods accordingly.

Comment: Since this is a bare Expo app I am not sure I am able to make use of multiple flavours (c.f. Release Channels?) or build types.